# Neovim Fugitive Merginal: Errors out when toggled on

Tags: neovim, vim-fugitive

Just installed [Merginal](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/merginal) (which is a addon to [Fugitive](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/fugitive-vim)) for Neovim and am getting this error when toggling the buffer (`:Merginal`):

[image]

I have my git setup properly and am able to use all other features of Fugitive. Anyone run into this before?

Thank you,

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest version of `Merginal`?
This plugin used to use a [deprecated](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/commit/aae36024b89e34db0280b5361633fb036b17951f) function from fugitive, but this [has been fixed](https://github.com/idanarye/vim-merginal/commit/c37bc6a0eb08d658d925dcbe2c34f65f87bc1ea8) in the master.

Comment: @jubnzv I installed it via Plug so I would image I would get the latest version everytime?

Comment: Yes, so you have the latest version. Then I'm not sure what's going wrong. I assume you should create an issue in the merginal's repo with the minimal reproducible example.

Comment: It really does look like the error fixed in @jubnzv's link, so I'd double check to see that you *do* have the latest version.: maybe something went wrong there. In any case this is not a Git issue, it's pure vim/vim-fugitive/merginal, so I've snipped the [tag:git] tag. (I wonder if SO should have a [tag:merginal]...) I'd recommend using cut and paste rather than screenshots in future questions, too: see [ask].

Comment: @torek I took your advice and went to my `my_plugins` folder which has all of Plug installs. I removed `vim-merginal` and `git clone merginal-repo` and it worked. Something wrong with Plug it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@torek has the correct suggestion.

If you are using Plug to install your plugins, its not pulling the latest code. Therefore:

1. Go to `my_plugins` or where ever your Plug plugins are installed.
2. Remove the `vim-merginal` repo completely
3. `git clone https://github.com/idanarye/vim-merginal.git`

Comment: You can avoid the remove-and-re-clone with `git fetch origin` followed by `git merge --ff-only`, or (as one command) `git pull --ff-only`. (But this is pretty minor, unless you have a very slow network connection.)